# Program type already present for ListenableFuture when adding Android WorkManager

Tags: android, gradle, android-workmanager

When adding `WorkManager` to my app, I'm getting the following build error.

> Program type already present:
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

I have used the pre-androidx version as mentioned on [Pre-AndroidX Dependencies](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#pre-androidx-deps)

```
def work_version = "1.0.1"
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
```

I tried checking the `gradle my_app:dependencies` to get the dependency tree too. I couldn't find what library is causing the collision.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the guava library as a whole to the project.

```
def work_version = "1.0.1"
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
implementation("com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre")
```